# Server Error in '/' Application when attempting to cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download a pdf using cURL and am getting stuck on a "Server Error in '/' Application" page. My code:

```
$url = "https://some.domain.com/Reports/Report?ReportID=123456"
$ch = curl_init($url);
$header = array ('Host: some.domain.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, implode(':', $arrayCiphers));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ASP.NET_SessionId=XXXXXXXX; __RequestVerificationToken_XXXXXXX=lots-of-alpha-numeric-characters");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://some.domain.com");

$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

Is there something else I can try or some more debugging I can do?

**[edit]** Apparently it's caused by one of my parameters. There are several parameters in the URL. `&Flag=True` seems to be causing the error. If I change it to `&Flag=False` I get a blank page.

Comment: What do you get if you hit the URL directly in the browser? Does it require authentication?

Comment: The pdf downloads if I access the URL directly in a browser. It does not require a username and password.

Comment: After your `curl_exec($ch)`, what is the output of `echo curl_error($ch)`?

Comment: I had `if (!curl_errno($ch)) { echo $output; } else { echo curl_error($ch); }` after `curl_exec($ch)`. I removed that and added `echo curl_error($ch)` and the page is now blank.

Comment: Add some context so we know what's happeneing: `if (!curl_errno($ch)) { echo "No error: ".$output; } else { echo "Error:".curl_error($ch); }`

Comment: That returns `No error: HTTP/1.1 200 OK` plus the rest of the headers. (Edit: I'm not sure if the cookies or header host are working correctly.)

Comment: So, it's apparently something with one of the variables. There is another variable `&Flag=True` that's causing the error. If I change it to `&Flag=False` I get a blank page.

Comment: Is the error appearing **on your server**, or is the "error message downloaded" **from the remote machine?**

Comment: If I understand the question, the error is on the remote machine. If I access the URL with a browser, it works fine. If I access it with my code above, the remote machine returns that error.

Comment: This is a typical ASP.net error message. Chances are there's a header missing from your request that the server is expecting, or you're not providing valid cookies. Sniff a browser request and add all the same headers to your cURL request.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I used the Request Headers from Chrome and added those in my cURL request. The only difference that I can see is it doesn't seem to be using the Host I'm specifying. The Request URL is different, too, if that can make a difference. The Response Headers are also different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was being caused because my curl request header did not include cookies that were required to download the file. Adding those cookies in the header fixed it.